# I can't seem to get the data from my serial COM11 (I am using an atmega328p) to my python code

Tags: python, c, serial-port, pyserial, usart

I am working on a line following robot. I get digital signals from my ir sensors in my PORTC pins. the car works fine. Now I need to plot a graph by sending a variable to my python code from the C code i am using. I have tried using USART_transmit and the using the read function. I cant seem to get the data to my python code. Here are my codes.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR F_CPU/16/BAUD-1
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void USART_Init( unsigned int ubrr);
unsigned char USART_Read();
void USART_Transmit( unsigned char data );

int main(void){
    USART_Init(MYUBRR);
    initIRSensor();
    int check = 0;
    while(1){

        if(PINC == 0b00000001){
            USART_Transmit(1);

        }

    }

    return 0;
}

void USART_Init( unsigned int ubrr)
{
    /*Set baud rate */
    /* UBRR0H contains the 4 most significant bits of the
    baud rate. UBRR0L contains the 8 least significant
    bits.*/  
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;


    /*Enable transmitter */
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)  |(1<<TXEN0);

    /* Set frame format: 8data */
    UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);
}
void USART_Transmit( unsigned char data )
{
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );

    /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
    UDR0 = data;
}

unsigned char USART_Read()
{
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)) );

    /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
    //UDR0 = data;
    return UDR0;
}
```

I want the value '1' to be sent to my python code so that i can make plots. This is my python code. I have given an increment whenever bulb 1 is high. The problem i have is that the read function doesn't work properly. The serial communication is working fine because i have used the ser.write function and it worked perfectly.The problem i have is with the read function. Hope anyone can help :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import serial
import keyboard

bulb1=0
ser = serial.Serial('COM11')
print(ser.name)
while 1:
    if(ser.read() == 1):
        bulb1+=1
```

Comment: (1) Try to fix it first using a terminal program (2) take an oscilloscop or other electronic stuff to check signals. - edited, just seen ín the headline ATMEGA..

Comment: Doesn't `ser.read()` return `bytes`? You're comparing it's return value against an `int`.  Instead of `1` did you mean `b'1'` or even `b'\x01'`?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked :)